# When Mashiach will come, will we still have the Avoda in the Yom Kippur Mussaf?

Tags: yom-kippur, messiah, korban, musaf

Presumably, the reason we have the Avoda in Mussaf is because of Uneshalma Parim Sefateinu - by saying (or learning) about sacrifices, it's as if we brought them. So if we're bringing real sacrifices we shouldn't need the second-best method.

Yet, we presumably had Mussaf, which is a mostly sacrifice prayer with little personal requests, in the time of the Beis Hamikdash and we didn't say that we are doing the real thing so why say a substitute.

So when Moshiach comes, will we say the Avoda?

Comment: Will we even have davening in the time of Mashiach?

Comment: @Scimonster מעלה בקדושה ולא מטה ... I can't find the exact quote but you get what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

I point to the Bracha in Shemoneh Esrei, "Retzei," which now focuses on the return of the sacrifices, but when the Beit HaMikdrash is rebuilt we will pray that the sacrifices are accepted and pleasing to God.

You can also see from the Ma'amadot that representatives of the non-Levites were sent to the Beit HaMikdash to pray that the sacrifices be accepted, and others participated in these prayers in their hometown.
http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/353479/maamadot

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: "So when Moshiach comes, will we say the Avoda?"
I thought it was obvious that I meant "yes."

Comment: Right. So...will we? You don't talk about Musaf at all, let alone that of Yom Kippur.

Comment: Adding in a source for your first sentence ("but when...") would greatly improve this answer.